# Get value returned from another method

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

In a Template helper, is it possible to get from a method a value returned by another method?

In example

```js
Template.postsList.helpers({
  posts: function () {
    return Posts.find({});
  },
  nextPath: function () {
    // how to return here the number of posts from the query
    // in the posts method?
  }
});
```

Comment: i dont know javascript so well, but couldn't you do a `return posts()`?

Comment: other then that, could you just make a `var` for the query inside of helpers and assign to the `var` before returning in that previous function then just return the `var` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just refactor the code so you have a shared way to obtain the posts cursor:

```js
var postsCursor = function() {
  return Posts.find();
};

Template.postsList.helpers
  posts: postsCursor,
  nextPath: function () {
    var count = postsCursor().count();
    // do something with count
  }
});
```